# It says:AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'time_taken'

Tags: python

```
import time


def profile(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        start_time = time.time()
        function(*args)
        end_time = time.time()
        function.time_taken = end_time-start_time
        return exec_time
    return wrapper

"""
@profile
def calsqr(a,b):
    return a**b
"""
@profile
def expensive_operation():
   import time
   time.sleep(3)
   return 1


print(expensive_operation.time_taken)
assert expensive_operation() == 1
```

Comment: You're only adding the attribute when calling the function. It doesn't exist before you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `time_taken` to wrapper function, and first call it in order to be able to access `time_taken` variable

```
import time


def profile(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        ret_value = function(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        wrapper.time_taken = end_time-start_time
        return ret_value

    return wrapper

"""
@profile
def calsqr(a,b):
    return a**b
"""
@profile
def expensive_operation():
   import time
   time.sleep(3)
   return 1


assert expensive_operation() == 1
print(expensive_operation.time_taken)
```